# Program to rotate an array; it's throwing Time Limit Exceed (TLE)? How to optimize and further fix using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, arrays

Given an unsorted array arr[] of size N, rotate it by D elements (clockwise).

Input:

The first line of the input contains T denoting the number of testcases. First line of each test case contains two space separated elements, N denoting the size of the array and an integer D denoting the number size of the rotation. Subsequent line will be the N space separated array elements.

Output:

For each testcase, in a new line, output the rotated array.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 200
1 <= N <= 107
1 <= D <= N
0 <= arr[i] <= 105
```

Example:
Input:

```
2
5 2
1 2 3 4 5 
10 3
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Output:

```
3 4 5 1 2
8 10 12 14 16 18 20 2 4 6
```

Explanation :

```
Testcase 1: 1 2 3 4 5  when rotated by 2 elements, it becomes 3 4 5 1 2.
```

I have already coded the same using Scanner class but it is throwing Time Limit Exceeded.

```
1. I need a better solution.
2. I read here that BufferedReader helps avoid TLE
3. I tried using it; but when i take input it throws NumberFormatException.
```

This is my Code:(Using Scanner class)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class rotat {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
 Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
 int t= sc.nextInt();
 while(t-->0){
     int s= sc.nextInt();
     int arr[]= new int[s];
     for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
         arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
     }
     int k= sc.nextInt();
     while(k-->0){
     int temp=arr[0];
     for(int j=1; j<s;j++){
        arr[j-1]=arr[j]; 
 }
 arr[s-1]=temp;
     }
 for(int j=0; j<s;j++){
        System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
 }
 System.out.println();

    }
}}
```

It runs well for custom test cases.

This is my code using Buffered Input: (I am new to using this; I have always used Scanner class so my code might be completely wrong.)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class rotat {
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        int t =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(t); 
 while(t-->0){
     int s= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
     System.out.println(s);
     int k= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
     System.out.println(k);
     int arr[]= new int[s];
     for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
         arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
     }

     while(k-->0){
     int temp=arr[0];
     for(int j=1; j<s;j++){
        arr[j-1]=arr[j]; 
 }
 arr[s-1]=temp;
     }
 for(int j=0; j<s;j++){
        System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
 }
 System.out.println();

    }
}}
```

Runtime Error:

```
Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5 2" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at GFG.main(File.java:13)
```

Comment: I don't think your TLE has anything to do with `Scanner`. You are rotating the array by 1 element for `D` times, which has a time complexity of `O(ND)`, and is not the most efficient way to do this...

Comment: @ImperishableNight thank you for pointing that out; i will try thinking of better ways.

Comment: @ImperishableNight I am also stuck at taking the input using BufferedReader like i do using Scanner; can you help me out with it?

Comment: Dont' use 3LAs here, unless they are in extremely common use.

Comment: Can you be more clear? @user207421

Comment: 3LA: three-letter acronym. See what I mean?

Comment: @user207421 I changed it, sir. I am new here, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BufferedReader takes the whole line as an input and when you give it "5 2" as input, it tries to parse it as an integer. Now there is the problem. I would suggest using StringTokenizer along with BufferedReader to overcome this.

```
while(t-->0){
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
   int s = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
   int k = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
   // to take new line in input
   StringTokenizer arrInput = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
   int[] arr = new int[s];
   for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
       arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrInput.nextToken());
   }
   int[] answer = new int[s];

   for(int j=0; j<s;j++){
       answer[(j-k+s)%s]=arr[j];
   }
   for(int j=0;j<s;j++){
       arr[j] = answer[j];
   }
}
//all you need to do is print your arr array.
```

Whenever you have more than one values in a single line, StringTokenizer can be used. It creates tokens of the string by breaking it at spaces and forming a group of string which can be accessed using that StringTokenizer.

Comment: I tried working this out using StringTokenizer too; throws Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
 at rotat.main(File.java:19) 

Line 19: where i take the array input.

Comment: can you post that code in your question? or share it using gfg ide?

Comment: I made a silly mistake in my answer. It was supposed to be arrayInput.nextToken(). Now this should work fine.

Comment: yeah got it. It was my fault. Do let me know if it works now or doesn't.

Comment: It works thank you, but still throws TLE; need to optimize my code.

Comment: If it works do accept this answer. I can see there is some scope for optimization. But using BufferedReader is better than Scanner in most cases.

Comment: The OP is complaining about a `TimeLimitExceededException`, and this answer does not solve or even explain it.

Comment: @user207421, if you can help; please do.

Comment: @user207421 The OP was concerned about how to take input from BufferedReader I helped him with that. He didn't ask to optimize the problem for him.

Comment: @Mike What you are trying to do is rotating the array one by one element "k" times. Try to do it in one shot.

Comment: Edited the answer. I think it should work now. Let me know if it doesn't. I didn't want to spoon feed him and his main concern was to take input using BufferedReader when there is more than one integer in a single line. Read the comment he has written below his question. @user207421

Comment: Glad I could help. Please make sure you explain your problem properly. Some people are wondering why are you using Scanner to rotate an array or whether you want to optimize the input or overall code.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why do you use `Scanner` to rotate an array?! To rotate an array (left or right) you could use the following trick.

```
ABCDEFG -> FGABCDE

1. GFEDCBA -> rotate A...G
2. FGEDCBA -> rotate G...F
3. FGABCDE -> rotate E...A
```

**Code**

```
private static void leftRotate(int[] a, int k) {
    k = k >= a.length ? a.length % k : k;

    for (int i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(a, i, j);
    for (int i = 0, j = a.length - k - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(a, i, j);
    for (int i = a.length - k, j = a.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(a, i, j);
}

private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

    class Main { 
        /*here we define funtion to left rotate arr[] of size n by d is number of rotation*/
        void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n) 
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) 
                leftRotatebyOne(arr, n); 
        } 
      
        void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n) 
        { 
            int i, temp; 
            temp = arr[0]; 
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; 
            arr[i] = temp; 
        } 
      
        /* utility function to print an array */
        void printArray(int arr[], int n) 
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
            }
    
          System.out.println();
        } 
      
        // This main method we test above functions 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            int n,d;;
            //Main=RotationClass
            
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
    
    //t define the number of testcases    
    int t = sc.nextInt();
            
        for(int k=0;k<t;k++){
           
            n=sc.nextInt();
            d=sc.nextInt();
    
            int[] array = new int[n]; 
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                array[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            
            Main rotate = new Main(); 
            rotate.leftRotate(array, d, n); 
            rotate.printArray(array,n); 
            
        } 
       }
    }
```